# How to solve 07002 too few parameters

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I have the following code:

```
        self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE Names SET Format = ?, FoodServiceBulkPack = ?, EachUPC = ?,
        EachWeight = ?, EachUOM = ?, QtyPerInner = ?, InnerPackUPC = ?, InnerWeight = ?,
        InnerUOM = ?, QtyPerCase = ?, CaseUPC = ?, CaseWeight = ?, CaseUOM = ?,
        QtyCasesperPallet = ?, CaseGTIN = ?, [Short Description] = ?, [Long Description] = ?,
        FrontImage = ?, RearImage = ?, Layflat = ?, Perishable = ?,
        IsMultiPack = ?, IsVarietyPack = ?, IsDisplayShipper = ?, PalletUPC = ?, PalletWeight = ?, PalletUOM = ?,
        PalletTi = ?, PalletHi =  = ?
        WHERE ((BrandName = """ + brandName + 
        ") AND ([ProductStyle /Category] = " + productStyle + 
        ") AND (ProductFlavor = " + productFlavor + ")) """, conv_list)
        self.con.commit()
```

I made sure number of elements in conv_list is the same as question marks. However, I get the following problem

```
    self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE Names SET Format = ?, FoodServiceBulkPack = ?, EachUPC = ?,   
    pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. 
    Expected 64. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Comment: what you have in your conv_list tuple? seems like they don't match with number of  parameters in your query string

Comment: Why are you mixing query parameters (`?` - good) with dynamic SQL (e.g., `" + productFlavor + "` - bad)?

Comment: Also, `Format` may be a reserved word in Access SQL. Try `UPDATE Names SET [Format] …`

Comment: The error message says that it expected 64 parameters, which is quite a bit more than the number of question marks.  Do `brandName`, `productStyle`, and/or `productFlavor` contain additional question marks?  It might be helpful to build the full query string by itself and print it, so you can see exactly what it's trying to do.

Comment: Also the double equal signs in `PalletHi =  = ?` seems like an error.

Answer (score 1):

Too many quotes, I guess. Try with:

```
    self.cursor.execute("UPDATE Names SET [Format] = ?, FoodServiceBulkPack = ?, EachUPC = ?,
    EachWeight = ?, EachUOM = ?, QtyPerInner = ?, InnerPackUPC = ?, InnerWeight = ?,
    InnerUOM = ?, QtyPerCase = ?, CaseUPC = ?, CaseWeight = ?, CaseUOM = ?,
    QtyCasesperPallet = ?, CaseGTIN = ?, [Short Description] = ?, [Long Description] = ?,
    FrontImage = ?, RearImage = ?, Layflat = ?, Perishable = ?,
    IsMultiPack = ?, IsVarietyPack = ?, IsDisplayShipper = ?, PalletUPC = ?, PalletWeight = ?, PalletUOM = ?,
    PalletTi = ?, PalletHi = ?
    WHERE ((BrandName = '" + brandName + "') AND ([ProductStyle /Category] = " + productStyle + ") AND (ProductFlavor = '" + productFlavor + "'))", conv_list)
    self.con.commit()
```

If *ProductStyle* is text, it must also be quoted like *Brandname*.